# find executables in my PATH with a particular string

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to quickly know whether an executable in my `$PATH` contains a particular string? For instance, I want to quickly list the executables that contain `SRA`.

The reason I'm asking is that I have several scripts with the characters `SRA` in them. The problem is that I always forget the starting character of the file (if I do remember, I use tab completion to find it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the paths in an array and then use `find` with its various options:

```
IFS=":" read -ra paths <<< "$PATH"
find "${paths[@]}" -type f -executable -name '*SRA*'
```

- `IFS=":" read -ra paths <<< "$PATH"` reads all the paths into an array, setting the field separator temporarily to `:`, as seen in [Setting IFS for a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33417264/1983854).
- `-type f` looks for files.
- `-executable` looks for files that are executable. You may use `-perm +111` instead in OSX ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1214935/38941)).

Since the `-executable` option is not available in FreeBSD or OSX, [ghoti nicely recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415921/find-executables-in-my-path-with-a-particular-string?lq=1#comment54622990_33416160) to use the `-perm` option:

```
find -perm -o=x,-g=x,-u=x
```

Comment: Why the loop? Why not just `find "${paths[@]}" -type f ...`?

Comment: Also, I believe this will output each filename twice -- once as the stdout of grep, and once as the default `-print` option of find. You could `grep -q` to use grep's return status alone.

Comment: @ghoti great info! I updated with your suggestion, many thanks.

Comment: Happy to be able to contribute to one of your answers. :)

Comment: @ghoti also I tested and it just shows the match once

Comment: @fedorqui when I run `IFS=":" paths=($PATH)` it hoses my $PATH variable by replacing all the `:` with spaces. Was this your intention?

Comment: @pcantalupo of course not and I am checking why this is happening. Based on [Setting IFS for a single statement](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92190/40596) I would use `IFS=: eval 'paths=($PATH)'`.

Comment: @pcantalupo by the way, to solve this, say `unset IFS` and it will be the space again.

Comment: @pcantalupo it doesn't replace anything, however you are printing it is making it seem like it is though.

Comment: Ah, right you are, `-print` is default if there is no `-ls` or `-exec`. For reference though, `find` in FreeBSD or OSX does not include an `-executable` option, that's a GNU findutils option. I believe you can get the same result using `-perm +u=x,g=x,o=x`.

Comment: @pcantalupo, after setting `IFS`, compare the output of `echo $PATH` with `echo "$PATH"`.  The issue is that your IFS variable is still set.

Comment: a weakness of this solution is that it will find executables in a deeper directory that contain SRA even though that executable is not in my path

Comment: @pcantalupo true this, to me the best command is the one Dummy0+1 offers. Since I don't want to copy his answer, I would go for that one : ) In the meantime, I will update using ghoti's nice suggestions.

Comment: @pcantalupo, you control that weakness with `find`'s `-depth` option.

Comment: @fedorqui, if you set two variables on a single command line, you just set two variables, you aren't setting the first one only for the set of the second. Oddly, `IFS=":" declare -a paths=($PATH)` doesn't appear to help. The best solution may be the old standby of copying `$IFS` to a temporary variable, to be restored afterwards.

Comment: @ghoti oh, I see. In fact this prompted me to ask this question: [Setting IFS for a single statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33416877/1983854)

Comment: Just answered that question, but as usual, I lost the race to chepner and anubhava. :-P

Comment: @ghoti also, updated to reflect your suggestion on FreeBSD, OSX. Thanks again!

Comment: another possible change here is to ignore errors from the find (as some paths in the PATH may be invalid), and to remove duplicates (as some paths may be in the path more than once), so `find "${paths[@]}" -type f -executable -name *SRA*' 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq`

Comment: and one more, sounds like a posix portable version of the `-executable`, is to use `-perm +111`, which is the only variant I could get working on a mac, and [comes from here](https://superuser.com/a/1214935/38941)

Comment: @BradParks thanks! Included that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -executable -name '*SRA*'
```

And if you happen to have spaces (or other hazardous characters) in the $PATH (the `<<<` trick borrowed from the answer of @fedorqui):

```
tr ":\n" "\\000" <<< "$PATH" | \
  xargs -0r -I{} -n1 find {} -maxdepth 1 -executable -name '*SRA*'
```

It also handles the empty $PATH correctly.

Comment: Same weakness as well, failing around path directories that include a space... A solution using `IFS=:` is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit clumsy:

```
find $(echo $PATH | tr : ' ') -name \*SRA\*
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a bash script that wraps this up for OSX, [based off this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416160/26510) on this page.

I think will work for other operating systems as well. Note that it also ignores errors, sorts the results, and only shows unique values too!

#### executables_in_path_matching_substring.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename "$0")
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

  returns a list of files in the path that match a substring

  usage: $ME SUBSTRING

  e.g.

  # Find all files in the path that have "git" in their name
  $ME git
EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  echo
  exit
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ "$1" == "help" ] || [ "$1" == '?' ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ] || [ "$1" == "h" ]; then
  show_help
fi

SUBSTRING="$1"
IFS=":" read -ra paths <<< "$PATH"
find "${paths[@]}" -type f -perm +111 -name "*$SUBSTRING*" 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq
```