# Setting IFS for a single statement

Tags: bash, ifs

On my `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release` I am doing some tests to [answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416160/1983854). The idea is to split a `:`-separated string and and each of its elements into an array.

For this, I try to set the `IFS` to `:` in the scope of the command, so that the split is automatic and `IFS` remains untouched:

```
$ myvar="a:b:c"
$ IFS=: d=($myvar)
$ printf "%s\n" ${d[@]}
a
b
c
```

And apparently `IFS` remains the same:

```
$ echo $IFS
                      # empty
```

The [BASH reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) says that:

> If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is
>   null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

However, then I notice that the `IFS` is kind of broken, so that `echo $myvar` returns `a b c` instead of `a:b:c`.

Unsetting the value solves it:

```
$ unset IFS
$ echo $myvar
a:b:c
```

But I wonder: what is causing this? Isn't `IFS=: command` changing `IFS` just in the scope of the command being executed?

I see in [Setting IFS for a single statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92190/40596) that this indeed works:

```
$ IFS=: eval 'd=($myvar)'
$ echo $myvar
a:b:c
```

But I don't understand why it does and `IFS=: d=($myvar)` does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was going to comment on this when I saw you use it, but it didn't occur to me until just now what the problem was. The line

```
IFS=: d=($myvar)
```

doesn't temporarily set `IFS`; it simply sets two variables in the current shell. (Simple commands can be prefixed with local environment settings, but an assignment statement itself is not a simple command.)

When you write

```
echo $IFS
```

`IFS` expands to `:`, but because `:` is the first character of `IFS`, it is removed during word splitting. Using

```
echo "$IFS"
```

would show that `IFS` is still set to `:`.

Comment: Great point about the difference between `echo $IFS` and `echo "$IFS"`. As everybody always says, quote your variables in bash.  :-)

Comment: It was the circularity of `IFS` being used to affect the display of `$IFS` that confused me initially; I was pretty sure assignment statements didn't have environments, but I couldn't immediately put my finger on why `echo $IFS` seemed to display the old value. :)

Comment: Niiiice and thanks for the answer indicating why I was doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Better still: `printf "%q\n" "$IFS"` since that shows the value of whitespace that $IFS may have

Comment: @dawg In this case, I'm only pointing out how to confirm that `IFS` doesn't have *any* whitespace in its value, but just the previously assigned `:`.

Answer (score 4):

`IFS` behaves fine with `read` on the same line:

```
myvar="a:b:c"
IFS=: read -ra d <<< "$myvar"
printf "%s\n" "${d[@]}"
a
b
c
```

Check value of `IFS`:

```
declare -p IFS
-bash: declare: IFS: not found
```

so clearly `IFS` has not been tampered in current shell.

Now check original input:

```
echo $myvar
a:b:c
```

or:

```
echo "$myvar"
a:b:c
```

Comment: Interesting and many thanks anubhava. Note what the other posters mention seems to be the problem: my command is executing two assignments. So what you suggest is clever: instead of two assignments, we now have one [temporal] assignment and a command.

Comment: As always, thanks a lot for your kind answer anubhava! It's a pity I cannot accept the three answers, since all of them add very valuable information

Comment: You're most welcome. You've indeed marked the right answer as accepted as @Chepner correctly explained the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can set set a variable that is valid for a single statement only if that statement is not itself a variable assignment.  For example:

```
$ foo=one bar=two
$ echo $foo
one
```

To make the second assignment part of a statement, you need ... some other statement.  As you've noticed, `eval` works.  In addition, `read` should work:

```
$ foo="one:two:three"
$ IFS=: read -r -a bar <<< "$foo"
$ declare -p bar
declare -a bar='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

Comment: Note that this issue arose in a question requiring POSIX-compliant code, which is why the here string wasn't considered.

Comment: Aaah so this is the issue, I couldn't understand why `eval` was making it work.

Comment: Thanks again. Pity I cannot accept the three answers, since I learnt much from them all!

Comment: My pleasure. And notwithstanding the fact that I diagnosed the issue first in the other Q, chepner's answer to this question was the only one that included the correct terminology of "simple commands". And of course, anubhava doesn't need any more points, he's already already earned an all-time high score. :)