# Strange behavior using read for validate string (bash script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I are creating a .sh using bash for validate the api sub folders versions

The objective is validate this strings into `APIS_BUILD` var and find all `.proto` files into `./proto` folder to compile into protobuffer Go file

```
# define subfolder apis to build
APIS_BUILD=(
    prototests/v1/
    prototests2/v2
    testfolder
)
# the "testfolder" are a invalid folder
```

Test cases:

```
prototestes/v1                      # valid
prototestes/v1/cobranca             # valid
prototestes/v1/cobrnaca/faturamento # valid
outrapastacomarquivosproto/v1       # valid
prototests                          # invalid
/prototests                         # invalid
```

Then, I created this script for validate the `APIS_BUILD` string array

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# text color
RED='\033[0;31m'  # RED
BLUE='\033[0;34m' # Blue
NC='\033[0m'      # No Color

# Underline color
UCyan='\033[4;36m' # Cyan

# define subfolder apis to build
APIS_BUILD=(
    prototests/v1
    cobrancas/v1
)
DST_DIR="."       # define the directory to store the build-in protofiles
SRC_DIR="./proto" # define the proto files folder

# Compile proto file
# $1 = Filename to compile
function compile() {
    protoc --go_out=$DST_DIR --proto_path=proto --go_opt=M$1=services \
        --go_opt=paths=import --go-grpc_out=. \
        $1
}

# Validate api_build's
function validateApiBuilds() {
    for t in ${APIS_BUILD[@]}; do
        IFS="/"
        read -a SUBSTR <<<"$t"
        if [ ${#SUBSTR[@]} -lt 2 ]; then
            printf "${RED}The API_BUILD value ${UCyan}\"${t}\"${RED} are declare wrong, please declare [api_folder]/[version_folder] (example: prototest/v1)${NC}\n" 1>&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

validateApiBuilds

for filename in $(find $SRC_DIR -name '*.proto'); do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    echo $filename
done
```

- The subfolder:

[image]

But I getting a strange behavior:

- If run the `.sh` file with the `validateApiBuilds` function the return for `$filename` is always `.`
- If run the `.sh` file without the `validateApiBuilds` function the return for `$filename` are getting the `testservice.proto` file

Pictures:

With `validateApiBuilds` function:

[image]

Without `validateApiBuilds` function:

[image]

---

All the variables:

```
# define subfolder apis to build
APIS_BUILD=(
    prototests/v1
    cobrancas/v1
)
DST_DIR="."       # define the directory to store the build-in protofiles
SRC_DIR="./proto" # define the proto files folder
```

Bash version:

```
$ bash --version                                  
$ GNU bash, versão 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Obs.: I changed the `validateApiBuilds` function to use a regex validation for strings into `API_BUILDS` variable. But I really wanted to know the reason for this behavior.

edit 2: The `make-proto.config` file

```
# define subfolder apis to build
APIS_BUILD=(
    prototests/v1
    cobrancas/v1
)
DST_DIR="."       # define the directory to store the build-in protofiles
SRC_DIR="./proto" # define the proto files folder
```

Comment: Please minimize your script to be a [mre], the _shortest possible thing_ that can be run without changes to check whether a specific problem is present -- we don't need the code checking which variables exist, f/e, unless the bug is specifically with those checks. We don't need code that prints colorful errors unless your problem is with color; etc.

Comment: BTW, `for filename in $(find $SRC_DIR -name '*.proto'); do` is an antipattern -- see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) describing why, and [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) describing what to do instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the behavior only occurs with all code above, if I put only the function and the "for" loop, the behavior not occurs

Comment: Surely not. I find it impossible to believe that it would stop happening if you took out the `if [[ -z "$APIS_BUILD" ]]; then` block, for example. So take out _as many things as you can_, while leaving in only the things you can't. If that means commenting out one line or block at a time, testing, and reverting if the problem no longer occurs, do that -- see also the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/ for guidance on how to build clear, minimal reproducers.

Comment: (Also, note that `echo $filename` is itself potentially buggy -- that's [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), or the Stack Overflow question [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566), or the http://shellcheck.net/ warning [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) -- running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here is a good idea in general).

Comment: ...another good place to start is using `set -x` to enable trace logging, so you can see the actual commands as they're run with variables expanded, and compare between working and broken scenarios.

Comment: The ```IFS="/"``` can possible changing the behavior of the ```find``` loop?

Comment: Definitely, yes. (That's part of why other mechanisms to iterate over `find`'s output are preferred, and documented in the Using Find link above).

Comment: ...that aspect of the question is duplicative of [setting IFS for a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416877/setting-ifs-for-a-single-statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `find` better

`for filename in $(anything)` is always an antipattern -- it splits values on characters in IFS, and then expands each result as a glob. To make `find` emit completely unambiguous strings, use `-print0`:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
    echo "$filename"
done < <(find "$SRC_DIR" -name '*.proto' -print0)
```

---

## Don't change IFS unnecessarily

Change your code to make the assignment to `IFS` be on the same line as the `read`, which will make `IFS` only be modified for that one command.

That is to say, instead of:

```
IFS=/
read -a SUBSTR <<<"$t"
```

...you should write:

```
IFS=/ read -a SUBSTR <<<"$t"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for IFS explain and the pattern for the loop